# How to avoid some folder to download ftp terminal?

Tags: ftp

Am logged ftp using terminal below command,

```
ftp hostname
username
password
cd ..
cd public_html
ls
prompt noprompt
lcd /var/xxx/mylocalpath
mget *
```

the above commands its working fine start download files ,But I want to ignore some folder for example my images folder having lot of size like 6Gb like that.Is it possible to avoid some folder when start download file in ftp terminal?

Comment: I hope You have required to change file permission in ftp

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-4555/wuftp-15.html check this link it is so helpful to you

Comment: thanq,but i can't ftpaccess file in my server.

Comment: you connected Your ftp

Comment: If You connect You ftp then You download File zila application and You can es=asly operate Your ftp data and work in graphic mode

Comment: Am already connnect and download file zilla application,Shall i remove and reinstall that again?am using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: so whats Problem File Zila is work on unix ,linux, mac, win. and many operating system